# How to get intellisense to work with a .egg-link package (installed in development mode)?

Tags: python, pip, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

In Visual Studio 2019, I'm trying to get intellisense to work with a package I installed using the command:

`pip install -e "git+https://github.com/bmoscon/cryptofeed.git/#egg=cryptofeed"[all]`

[Here are the docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support) explaining what it does. I called it using my projects virtual environment and everything seemed to work out okay (i.e. all the files seemed to download and link correctly).

The problem I am having is the main package itself (cryptofeed) isn't being picked up by intellisense (it says, "unresolved import cryptofeed"), while all the other dependency packages that were installed with it are recognized fine.

After doing some reading and some tests, I'm very confident that the reason it isn't working has to do with how packages are installed "development mode". Inside my `./env/Lib/site-packages` folder, I can see that cryptofeed is an `.egg-link` file (more info on that [here](https://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/setuptools/doc/formats.txt)). Does Visual Studio handle these files (or just the whole "editable/development mode" thing in general) for intellisense? Is there something I am misunderstanding or did wrong here?

I guess it's worth mentioning also that I read these [MS' docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/search-paths?view=vs-2019#:%7E:text=If%20your%20PYTHONPATH%20environment%20variable,environment%20associated%20with%20the%20project.) which made me think maybe I could do a "hacky" solution by just adding a search path to the source code, but that didn't appear to solve or do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally got it working. I've tried it on multiple repos/packages and it worked on all of them.

The solution involves adding a search path manually (as mentioned above in my question post). I don't know exactly why, but it seems the added search path must target root directory of the *python* package. It wouldn't work If I just added the directory containing the source code.

i.e. If the installed package's source directory contains sub-directories like:

```
pkgDir
├── pkgName
├── pkgName.egg-info
└── tests
```

In this example, you should try adding `pkgDir`, not `pkgName` as a search path. This directory also contains other important files, e.g. `setup.py`; and maybe one of these files are necessary for intellisense's functioning? IDK.

Sometimes packages support multiple languages, so be sure to add the directory that is for ***python***. IIRC, it's the same directory you set for the "subdirectory" flag/setting when installing the package.

**e.g:** `pip install -e "git+https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt.git/#egg=ccxt&subdirectory=python"`

You may have not needed to use the `subdirectory` setting if `setup.py` was located at the root, but essentially what this means is that it seems to work with the directory that contains `setup.py` (and the .egg-info folder).

---

Again, I don't really know why this works exactly. The folder you need to target may look very different from the one I described. Maybe someone else can give a more concrete answer.

I should mention, **intellisense takes a while to load (probably depending on size of package).** Don't be too quick to assume that the search path is wrong (for me it took about 1 minute to start working from when I added the search path).

According the MS docs for Visual Studio (2019) python support options and settings [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/python-support-options-and-settings-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019), it has an option for "Update search paths when adding linked files". This is enabled by default and didn't seem to work for this purpose; it seems it refers to a different kind of linked file.